# Many to Many association select query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables.

posts, tags and posts_tags for association

**posts**

```
id, title .content
```

**tags**

```
id, name
```

**posts_tags**

```
post_id,
tag_id
```

I just want to get all the tags that are associated with specific post, when I select a post, like this

post
id, title, content, tags

I'm stuck with writing SQL query, it would be grateful if someone help me, please

Comment: what did you tried already? Please share the query.

Comment: select posts.title, posts.content, tag.name as tags from posts,tags
left join posts_tags on posts.id = posts_tags.post_id
left join posts_tags on tags.id = posts_tags.tag_id
where post_id = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be simply achieved by the `Join`

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.content, t.name  FROM posts as p
INNER JOIN posts_tags as pt on p.id=pt.post_id
INNER JOIN tags as t on t.id = pt.tag_id
```

For one Post

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.content, t.name  FROM posts as p
INNER JOIN posts_tags as pt on p.id=pt.post_id
INNER JOIN tags as t on t.id = pt.tag_id
WHERE p.id = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, can I use DISTINCT to t.name to get only one row when I use WHERE condition?

Comment: If you need the data for one post id then use the "WHERE p.id = 1"

Comment: Distinct t.name means, you got the duplicate tag name when you use the above query with "Where"

Answer (score 0):

Lets try this

```
select posts.title, posts.content, tag.name as tags from posts
inner join posts_tags on posts.id =  posts_tags.post_id
inner join tags on posts_tags.tag_id = tags.id
```

But its more better to use  alias for table name

```
select p.id, p.title, p.content, t.name from posts as p
inner join posts_tags as pt on p.id=pt.post_id
inner join tags as t on t.id = pt.tag_id
```